# Using Ag-Grid enterprise with a JS framework (React, Vue, Angular)

Tags: angular, reactjs, vue.js, ag-grid

I can't find any supported bindings for any of the major frameworks when it comes to Ag-Grid. They exist for the community edition but not for enterprise. I'm running into an issue now where I think I don't have access to one of the enterprise features because I'm forced to use community bindings.

How are people using enterprise with a JS framework? Mine is Vue.js if that matters, but I noticed there are no bindings for React or Angular either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I discovered that enterprise features are still available while using community bindings. I thought I didn't have access to a certain feature because I was using the material theme, which doesn't support a few features. I've since gone back to the Balham theme and have everything I need available.

You can use `@ag-grid-community/vue` in conjunction with `@ag-grid-enterprise/AllModules` and it works just fine.

Answer (score 0):

To use enterprise [ag-grid](/questions/tagged/ag-grid), you simply have to install `ag-grid-enterprise` npm package, provide license key and use enterprise features.

It doesn't matter which framework you use.

1. The basic library: `ag-grid-community`.
2. Enterprise version: `ag-grid-enterprise` - install and use if you'd like to use enterprise features [optional]
3. Framework specific libraries, i.e. `ag-grid-angular`, `ag-grid-react`, `ag-grid-vue`

No.3 just provides us framework specific wrappers on ag-grid. That's how [ag-grid](/questions/tagged/ag-grid) has provided its packages.

> How are people using enterprise with a JS framework? Mine is Vue.js if that matters, but I noticed there are no bindings for React or Angular either.

- If you are using `ag-grid-vue`, just use it with your [vue](/questions/tagged/vue) application.
- If you want to use enterprise feature, install `ag-grid-enterprise` with license key and start using enterprise feature.
- It'll show you console errors if you try to access any enterprise features without using license key.

Hope that answers your question. Let me know if you need any further clarification.

Comment: Hey thanks for the answer - Ag-Grid has moved on to the module based architecture so ag-grid-vue doesn't actually work (JS complains it can't find the node_module if I install it). So, for community, I've been using @ag-grid-community/vue which is the vue module for community. Wondering if there's an equivalent for enterprise.

Comment: I have been using `ag-grid-community`, `ag-grid-enterprise` and `ag-grid-angular` since v17.0.0; recently upgraded to `22.1.1` - haven't need to do any such change for that. But I think you install `ag-grid-enterprise/all-modules` - as per what I've just checked on the example plunks on `ag-grid` site.